# Why does parameter like '-n' or '-yn' not work when apply for task manager

Tags: apache-flink

Running the follow command to submit job to yarn, but the allocate number of task manager is not expected. Cluster has enough resource <220vcores, 720G mem>

```
/data/clusterserver/flink-1.7.2/bin/flink run -m yarn-cluster -yn 4 -ys 2  /data/clusterserver/flink-1.7.2/examples/batch/WordCount.jar --input hdfs:///tmp/wordcount.txt --output hdfs:///tmp/count.result
```

```
2019-04-10 15:04:57,397 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli                 - No path for the flink jar passed. Using the location of class org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor to locate the jar
2019-04-10 15:04:57,397 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli                 - No path for the flink jar passed. Using the location of class org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor to locate the jar
2019-04-10 15:04:57,405 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli                 - The argument yn is deprecated in will be ignored.
2019-04-10 15:04:57,405 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli                 - The argument yn is deprecated in will be ignored.
2019-04-10 15:04:57,554 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor           - Cluster specification: ClusterSpecification{masterMemoryMB=2048, taskManagerMemoryMB=2048, numberTaskManagers=4, slotsPerTaskManager=2}
2019-04-10 15:04:58,017 WARN  org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor           - The configuration directory ('/data/clusterserver/flink-1.7.2/conf') contains both LOG4J and Logback configuration files. Please delete or rename one of them.
2019-04-10 15:05:01,419 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor           - Submitting application master application_1554348641734_0105
2019-04-10 15:05:01,446 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl         - Submitted application application_1554348641734_0105
2019-04-10 15:05:01,447 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor           - Waiting for the cluster to be allocated
2019-04-10 15:05:01,450 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor           - Deploying cluster, current state ACCEPTED
2019-04-10 15:05:05,747 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor           - YARN application has been deployed successfully.
Starting execution of program
```

As we can see from INFO log, the parameters send to yarn is 
 `{masterMemoryMB=2048, taskManagerMemoryMB=2048, numberTaskManagers=4, slotsPerTaskManager=2}` , however, there is only one taskManager from flink WebUI.

Using
 `yarn-session.sh` with `-n` also meets the same issue, namely control number of taskManagers from command line is not working.

- flink version 1.7.2
- hadoop version 2.8.5 (Capacity Scheduler)
- java: 1.8.0_91

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Flink `1.5`, Flink supports full resource elasticity. This means that Flink is capable to dynamically start and stop `TaskManagers` when running on Yarn. A consequence is that you no longer need to specify the number of containers/`TaskManagers` for a Flink cluster on Yarn. That's why Flink no longer respects the `-n`/`-yn` option.

Instead, Flink considers the job's parallelism to calculate how many slots are necessary to execute the job and then starts as many `TaskManagers` as are needed to fulfill the slot requirements.

You can find more information about the deployment changes [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/release-notes/flink-1.5.html#update-configuration-for-reworked-job-deployment) and [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/release-notes/flink-1.7.html#support-for-multi-slot-taskmanagers).

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate reply. Then the latest document described [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/ops/deployment/yarn_setup.html#run-a-flink-job-on-yarn) is not update in time?

Comment: You are right. The documentation is outdated. I've just pushed a fix to correct the current usage.